# Является ли "опять же" вводным оборотом?

Tags: наречия, вводные-слова, пунктуация

Является ли "опять же" вводным оборотом и нужно ли выделять это выражение запятыми? На ум приходит сходство с опять-таки, которое постановки знаков не требует. Но все же у "опять же" более отчетливая интонация вводного выражения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение "опять же" может являться вводным словом (обособляется) или обстоятельством (не обособляется).

Это вводное слово со значением "кроме того, к тому же", если оборот стоит в начале предложения (части сложного предложения) и при этом структура предложение такова, что его можно интонационно выделить, например: "Опять же, ведь не быть тебе там целый век, всё равно увезут".

Это обстоятельство в других случаях, когда оборот тесно связан со структурой предложения: "Опять же только начальство знало, что из этого получится". "Но самих сторублевок они опять же не видели".

*Примечание.* В текстах 19-го - начала 20-го века оборот часто выделялся двоеточием: "И опять же: голос его был такой, что просился в душу".

Answer (score 1):

*Опять же* неустойчиво вводное, решение об обособлении принимает автор: *опять же* обособляется при желании говорящего привлечь внимание к какому-либо факту (*= обратите внимание*), интонационно выделяется; не обособляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия (*= опять, снова*), интонационно не выделяется.

Ср.: Косвенно, опять же, (= обратите внимание) это задевает и Венечку.
Косвенно опять же (= снова) это задевает и Венечку.

Есть тенденция наречие *опять же* чаще использовать в функции обстоятельства и не обособлять.

Comment: Иногда это авторское решение, если оба варианта произношения возможны. Но можно так построить предложение, что обособлять приходится обязательно  ввиду несочетаемости со структурой предложения, например: Опять же, стоит ли ехать так далеко".